# Autocompletion/Restoring of input form fields that are created dynamically on navigation

Tags: html, dom, browser, browser-cache, web-component

Assume I have an `<input>` element on an HTML page. When I fill in a value, navigate forth to another page and navigate back, that value is usually restored:

1) In Firefox, the whole page state is being restored because of the BFCache: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_BFCache. (That means even the state of a running script is being restored.)

2) In Chrome, the fast page cache does not seem to work (so the page is reset to the original state), but the values of the input fields are being retained.

Now if I add an `<input>` field dynamically by a script, in Firefox the value will still be restored (because of the fact that everything is being in restored).

In Chrome, however, the Javascript to create the `<input>` field has to run again, so that this input field appears as a brand new to the engine, meaning that no value is being restored.

So my question is: How to implement Chrome's functionality 2) with dynamically generated `<input>`s (or how to give Chrome a hint about the identity of an input field).

(One reason why I am interested in all this are the proposed custom elements: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html. Using this or the polyfills at https://github.com/mozilla/web-components/blob/master/src/document.register.js or https://github.com/Polymer/CustomElements means that one is going to create a lot of (input) elements programmatically and for a good user experience they should work as the built-in elements.)

Answer (score 1):

> One work around I thought of is to use `window.history.replaceState` whenever the value of the input element changes to store it in the browser's history. But I am wondering whether I can hook directly into the browser's autocomplete functionality so that I do not have to repeatedly call replaceState.
>
> There is another workaround: Instead of storing the value (whenever it is changed) of a dynamically generated input in the browser history using the history API, one could create one static hidden `<input>` field that holds the page's state and for which we rely on the browser's ability to restore its value.
>
> Instead of using the input event on the `<input>` fields to detect changes to be saved in the current session's history entry, one could also listen for `pagehide` events to save the current values. This may be a bit more performant. However, this does not work with storing state in hidden input fields because any changes after the pagehide event are discarded (at least by Chrome).